# Match everthing except the regular expresion pattern in Tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I want to match the highlighted lines below which are outside of function definitions. I tried writing a regex pattern(Function.*?}) to match the complete function definition but I want to match all the other lines which are outside of function definition.

Function circuit1 {

I0 (n1 n2 n3) model

}

**I1 (n1 n2 n3) model**

Function circuit2 {

I2 (n1 n2 n3) model

}

**I3 (n1 n2 n3) model**

Comment: Finding matching braces is not something a regular expression is particularly good at.

Answer (score 4):

Since the data you want to parse looks *kind of* like Tcl, you could declare your own DSL to parse it as a Tcl script.

I'm going to use a safe interpreter to keep any potentially malicious stuff hidden.

```
set safe [interp create -safe]
interp eval $safe {
    # ignore Functions
    proc Function args {}
    # but keep everything else
    set wanted {}
    proc unknown args {lappend ::wanted $args}
}
interp invokehidden $safe source ./file
set lines_to_keep [interp eval $safe {set wanted}]
puts [join $lines_to_keep \n]
```

```
I1 (n1 n2 n3) model
I3 (n1 n2 n3) model
```

Comment: The data is not TCL script, it looks like that but not.

Comment: @Akhil It just has to look enough like tcl to be parsed by `source`. Doesn't need to be actual tcl.

Answer (score 1):

To keep everything except whatever matches your regexp, you can use `regsub` to replace the matching parts with nothing:

```
regsub -all "Function.*?}" $input {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how helpful this will be, but you could ignore anything that matches this:
https://regex101.com/r/HBfYzS/1

I tried using a negative lookahead, but wasn't met with much success because of quantifiers.

Not really a direct answer, but might be a small workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions aren't designed to do brace counting (there's a theoretical difference in the complexity of matching automata required). But Tcl does have a built-in brace (and bracket) matcher, `info complete`, provided you're willing to accept a few syntax constraints. They're usually just fine on vaguely programming-ish inputs, and are definitely fine on your sample input.

```
set accumulate ""
foreach line [split $inputData "\n"] {
    if {$accumulate ne ""} {
        # Add in the line *with newline separator*
        append accumulate \n $line
        # If it's brace-balanced...
        if {[info complete $accumulate]} {
            # ... drop the accumulated lines; we're not interested in them from here on
            set accumulate ""
        }
    } elseif {[regexp {^\s*Function\s+\w+\s+\{\s*$} $line]} {
        # Start to collect lines to skip
        set accumulate $line
    } else {
        # Found what we're looking for
        puts "This is a line of interest: $line"
    }
}
```

Note that I've used a regular expression to determine when to start matching, and the brace matching mode handling comes before that (so that any nested `Function` won't make things go wrong).